# Is this the only way to filter the right table in a left outer join?

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I have customer balances stored in their own table.  the customer balances table gets a new set of records every day (reflecting the balance that day) but contains balances for other days (yyyy-mm-dd).  I wanted to get all UK customers from `accountinformation` and their balances yesterday from `balances`.  I wanted to include rows from `accountinformation` even where there is no corresponding record (for yesterday) in `balances`...

```
select firstname,lastname,accountnumber,balance from accountinformation i 
left outer join balances b 
on i.accountnumber = b.account
where country = 'UK' and status = 'OPEN'
and (b.date = '2014-04-10' or b.date is null)
```

... it did not satisfy the requirement to show rows from `accountinformation` if there is no corresponding row in `balances`.  I had to write the query like this...

```
select firstname,lastname,accountnumber,balance from accountinformation i 
left outer join (select * from balances where date = '2014-04-10') b 
on i.accountnumber = b.account
where country = 'UK' and status = 'OPEN'
```

.. to get the desired behavour.   In the interests of correctness I want to know if there is a more correct way to filter the left table in a `left outer` join?

Comment: Maybe try `left outer join balances b on i.accountnumber = b.account and b.date='2014-04-10'`, omitting `and (b.date = '2014-04-10' or b.date is null)` from the where clause.

Comment: By the way, your first statement would work as intended on Sybase ASE, and probably on MySQL too.

Comment: .. so include the filter in the 'on' part?  That rings a bell.  I'll try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might be able to do

```
select firstname,lastname,accountnumber,balance from accountinformation i 
left outer join balances b 
on i.accountnumber = b.account and b.date = '2014-04-10'
where country = 'UK' and status = 'OPEN'
```

Comment: Hanno Binder, posted few seconds before. If it works he should get credit.

Comment: I think your answer more clearly shows what the point is than my sloppy comment. :)

Comment: What's the difference in putting `b.date = '2014-04-10'` as a third condition in the WHERE clause as opposed to this?

Comment: Thankyou.  This works,  and now that I see it it makes sense too!

Comment: knightwisp best way I can explain for how I think it works, having it as where condition limits the query results. Having it on the join limits the joining table results. If that makes sense lol

Comment: @Knightwisp, difference is: One version does work on SQL-Server, the other one doesn't :) As I commented above: There can't be too much rationale behind this specific behaviour since other RDBMS don't care which variant you use.